Certificate issue in web app using AWS certificate manager
I've created a multi-domain certificate in AWS Certificate Manager, specifically in the Ohio region. My web application, built with NestJS and NextJS, is hosted on EC2, and I'm using a Load Balancer configured with the certificate.
Occasionally, when browsing the application, it displays as "Not Secure." Upon inspecting the certificate, it sometimes shows an unexpected or incorrect certificate, as seen in the attached screenshots.
Additionally, I have multiple applications running on the same EC2 instance across different ports, managed through Nginx configuration.
A simple refresh temporarily resolves the SSL issue, but it intermittently reappears.
What might be causing this issue?



Do you have redirect rule on your Application Load Balancer HTTP->HTTPS?

...it displays as "Not Secure."... There is always more information that comes along with that error.  You need to provide that additional information. Also, what does the certificate look like when you don't get an error?

@Vasko Yes there is a redirect rule.
HTTP:80
Redirect to HTTPS://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query}
Status code: HTTP_301

@PresidentJamesK.Polk There is no error. It is simply like a regular Non Secure page that says "Your connection is not private"
